# Internal DNS failing

Tags: server, dns, bind

I have recently moved to a new DNS server and copied all my settings.  I have an issue, I can't figure out.

All Forwarding resolution to public names works always.
Internal names fail
If I login to my DNS server and ping just one local name, all internal resolution starts working.
After a while, not sure how long, internal DNS fails again until I login to the DNS server and ping an internal server.

I suspect this has to do with caching, but I'm not sure why this config worked on my old server and not my new server.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give some more information about which DNS server you're using and what the message is when it fails?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Bind9 on Ubuntu 16.04 Server.  Connecting to a host in the internal zone file from a client machine fails, until I ping that host from the console of the server.  After that the client will work.

How long it works, I haven't been able to work out because it works for a while.